# Let $B$ be a countable set, and suppose there exists an injective function $f\colon A \to B$. Show that $A$ is at most countable.

Tags: calculus

Here was my first thought. Let's assume $A$ is not at most countable, i.e. it is uncountable. Then, that would mean $|A| \gt |B|$. This means $\not\exists f\colon A \to B$ such that $f$ is injective, as one of the requirements of an injective function is that it is one to one. If the size of the original set is greater than that of the set being mapped to, it is impossible for each value in $A$ to be mapped to a unique value in $B$; there would need to be a value in $B$ that is mapped to by more than one value in $A$. This contradicts the fact that $\exists f\colon A \to B$ such that $f$ is injective. Therefore, $A$ must be at most countable.

However, I have a feeling that this proof falls apart at the very beginning when stating that $|A| \gt |B|$. Although this logically makes sense in my head, I sense that stating $\infty \gt \infty$, even when they are different "sizes" of infinity is troublesome. Could someone point me in the right direction for a more rigorous form of this proof? Thank you.

Note: countable <=> countably infinite.

Comment: Which definition of countable are you using?

Comment: I think you are asked to prove that any infinite cardinality not equal to countable is greater than countable. In other words, you need to prove there are no cardinality in between finite and countable. (If you haven't proved that cardinality is a linear order, then there are even more possibilities such as incomparable sizes).

Comment: @Lucas $A$ is countable $\Rightarrow A$ ~ $\mathbb{N}$

Comment: Use the definite of countable and at most countable directly.  There is an bijective function $\phi:\mathbb N \to B$.  We have $f:A \to B$ is injective.   We want to prove there is a surjective map $\psi: \mathbb N \to A$.  So.... make one (using $f$ and $\phi$)

Answer (score 1):

You can consider, for example, $A$ **at most countable** if *there is a surjective map $\alpha: \mathbb{N} \to A$*, which is equivalently to the *existence of an injective map $\beta: A \to \mathbb{N}$*. It was proved, for example, in Lemma 1.1 of *Mathematical Logic* by Ebbinghauss, Flum and Thomas.

By hypothesis you know that there is an injective map from $\beta: B \to \mathbb{N}$. Now, if you consider the composition $A \to B \to \mathbb{N}$, what you get?

Comment: Would you be able to directly write $A \to \mathbb{N}$ directly following from $A \to B \to \mathbb{N}$ or no?

Comment: @robertlewison $A \to B \to \mathbb{N}$ is a composition (of injective) maps, so this composition is a map $A \to \mathbb{N}$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we take the following to be true:
$$\forall X,Y\in Sets:\big[\text{ } |X|\leq |Y| \Leftrightarrow (\exists f_{injective}:X\hookrightarrow Y)\big].$$
If $B$ is **countable** (i.e. $|B|=|\mathbb{N}|$), then $\exists g:B\hookrightarrow \mathbb{N}$ and $\exists h:\mathbb{N}\hookrightarrow B$.
Hence if $\exists f:A\hookrightarrow B$, we may form the composite:
$$g\circ f:A\hookrightarrow \mathbb{N}$$
which yields $|A|\leq |\mathbb{N}|$. (Note composition preserves injectivity). 
Reading this off, $A$ is at most countable. $\square$

---

Comment: What does the ↪ symbol mean here?

Comment: Here it stands for an injective map since we are dealing with Sets, in other places it may stand for a monomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is injective then the cardinalities of $A$ and $f(A)$ are equal. As $f(A)\subset B,$ then $f(A)$ is at most countable, so is $A.$